# Populate bar graph from array with core plot

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dynamic, core-plot

I am trying to populate bar chart plot with an NSArray to dynamically update every time the view is called.

The array looks like this: `Motor = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"100", @"200", @"345", @"476", @"512", nil];`

and here is how I am calling the creation in

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index{

        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Motor"]) {
              return [Motor objectAtIndex:index];
        }
}
```

Any help would be very good.

Comment: You are returning string where you should return NSNumber...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you implemented this method ?

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
```

Also, you never test the field for which the value will be return.
You should try this.

```
- (NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
    NSNumber* value;
    if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Motor"]) 
    {
        // The location of the bar
        if(fieldEnum == CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation)
        {
            value = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:index];
        }
        // The value/height of the bar
        else if(fieldEnum == CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip)
        {
            value = [Motor objectAtIndex:index];
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are adding NSString values to array @"100"; is string value. So when you are returning a value you are returning string and it should be NSNumber.

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index{

        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Motor"]) {
              NSString *value = [Motor objectAtIndex:index];
               return [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[value integerValue]];// this will return number value with array walues. 
        }
         return [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0];//will return zero you can return whatever you want
}
```